# Updating server from Kendo Color picker inside kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**The Problem**

So i am currently trying to implement a color picker inside of a Kendo grid, that will hopefully send the chosen color to my Sql Table. Unfortunately, It doesn't seem as though the Update controller is being reached. I am relatively new to Kendo UI, so there might be some incredibly dumb errors shown.

*Questions*

I guess my main question would be: How can i call the update method when update is clicked on the grid. Essentially, the color picker and the edit command are showing up in beautiful fashion. I just want to know how i can be sure that the method is being called when 'Update' is clicked, seeing as it is not reaching my controller. Feel free to ask if you need to see more code or perhaps a screen shot.

**Code**

*Config.cshtml ( Grid )*

```
@model IEnumerable<STZN.Models.AGCData.ErrorCode>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Config";
}


@section HeadContent{
<script src="~/Scripts/common.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#grid").kendoGrid({
               editable: "inline",
               selectable: "row",
               dataSource: {
                   schema: {
                       model: {
                           id: "error_code",
                           fields: {
                               color: { type: 'string' }
                           }
                       }
                   },

                   transport: {

                       read: {
                           type: "POST",
                           dataType: "json",
                           url: "@Url.Action("ErrorCodes")"
                       },
                       update: {
                           type: "POST" ,
                           dataType: "json",
                           url: "@Url.Action("UpdateErrorCodes")",

                       }
                   }
               },

               columns: [
                   { command : [ "edit" ] },
                   {
                       field: "error_code", title: "Error Code",

                   },
                   {
                       field: "error_description", title: "Error Description"
                   },
                   {
                       field: "color",
                       width: 150,
                       title: "Color",
                       template: function (dataItem) {
                           return "<div style = 'background-color: " + dataItem.color + ";'&nbsp;</div>"
                       },
                       editor: function (container, options) {
                           var input = $("<input/>");
                           input.attr("color",options.field);
                           input.appendTo(container);
                           input.kendoColorPicker({
                               value: options.model.color,
                               buttons: false
                           })
                       },

                   }

               ]
           });
       });


    </script>
}
```

*Update Controller*

```
public JsonResult UpdateErrorCodes(ErrorCode model)
        {


            using (var db = new AgcDBEntities())
            {
                db.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                var data = db.ErrorCodes.Where(d => d.error_code == model.error_code).Select(x => new
                {
                    error_code = x.error_code,
                    description = x.error_description,
                    color = x.color,
                });

                return new JsonResult()
                {
                    JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                };
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to fix my issue by adding an additional input attribute to my editor function in the "color" field. It looks like this:

```
input.attr("data-bind","value:" + options.field);
```

There are still some present issues (unrelated  to the fix/server update) , but as far as updating to the server, It work's as intended.